# Tipped triangular weir

Tags: open-channel-flow

Can someone tell me what influence an angled wall has on the flow over a triangular weir compared to a "normal" vertical one if the wall is angled against the upstream as in the picture?
[image]

Comment: Make both and test them. A good learning experience.

Comment: I do not have that option

Comment: TLTR: looks like google may be your friend: https://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/publication_3_3905_6015.pdf

Comment: https://www.openchannelflow.com/blog/8-avoidable-errors-when-measuring-open-channel-flow

Comment: Thank you but both links are with pure vertical wall

Comment: And warn you to make sure the wall is vertical… as the error gets large…

Comment: The formula for flow over a triangular weir where the wall is vertical is widely documented. However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how an outward rotation of the wall affects the flow

Comment: You did not read one of the links I gave you very well then.

Comment: Yes it just says it has a significant impact but does not say anything about how it impacts?

Comment: They give you a reason, again read carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that at high flow rates the flow over an angled weir would tend to push more water over the weir.  At lower rates there would be no difference.  I imagine you owuld need to determine this emperically if this were the only way to build your weir.

Comment: As one of the references I gave points out that the angle of the notch affects how the water sticks to, or separates from, the notch then that causes errors - and the reference point out that they can be large. So not so sure about your "no difference"...